# vertical reaction arrow pointing to one horizontal reaction arrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I'm having trouble writing the arrows below, can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answers.

Comment: Then please consider accepting one of the answers. This is the "normal" procedure here in order to "close" a question.

Comment: So far you did not accept a single answer. By accepting an answer you show other readers that the answer was helpful and you show "thanks" to the author of the helpful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion in chemfig without subscheme:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{H_2O} 
\+ 
\chemfig{HCO^{+}}
\arrow(--[xshift=-33pt,yshift=25pt]){->[*{0}\chemfig{H_3O^{+}}]}[-90]
\chemfig{HCR=[90,,2]O}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<->>}
\chemfig{RCH_2-[-90,,2]Y}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have not seen your very nice answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, using subschemes. The vertical arrow leaves the middle of the upper subscheme and points to the middle of the lower subscheme.

```
\schemestart

\chemfig{A}

\+

\chemfig{B}

\arrow{->}

\chemleft[

\subscheme{

\chemfig{C}

\arrow{<->}

\chemfig{D}

}

\chemright]

\arrow{->[*{0}\chemfig{H_3O^{+}}]}[-90,1.2]

\subscheme{

\chemfig{E}

\arrow{<<->}[0,1.2]

\chemfig{F}

}

\schemestop
```

The result is:

[image]